# Поднять дамп oracle database с Linux на Windows

Tags: linux, база-данных, oracle, dump

Такая ситуация, есть дамп сделанный утилитой expdp на машине с Red Hat 5.2. и Oracle Database 11. Есть ли какие то варианты импортировать его в базу на машине с Windows и Oracle Database 11?

Answer (score 1):

Теперь вам нужно запустить `impdp` на машине под управлением Windows.

Дампы в Oracle Database являются полностью кроссплатформенными, хоть и хранятся в проприетарном бинарном формате.